# When I download mp3 file in Flutter, I can't play actual song that i have downloaded

Tags: node.js, flutter, download, mp3, video-player

Error is in flutter:: `java.io.eofexception`

Mp3 file is downloaded succesfully in specified path, but when i'm trying to play, the mp3 starts playing in just a few seconds and then stops.

I have tried so many packages that are for sounds, but with the all is the same error.

Maybe the error is in server side. I don't know. But in server side mp3 is downloaded successfully without any problem.

My download code in flutter:

```
Future<bool> downloadAudioMp3(String url) async {
  Dio dio = Dio();
  var directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  await dio.download(url, "${directory.path}/MyFristVideo.mp3", 
    onReceiveProgress: (rec, total) {
    print ("Downloading mp3::${((rec / total) * 100).toStringAsFixed(0) + 
   "%"}");
  });
  print ("Downloaded");
  return true;
}
```

My server side code::

```
ytdl.getInfo(video_path, function(err, info){
  var videoReadableStream = ytdl(video_path, { filter: 'audioonly'});
  if (err) throw new ThrowErrorWithStatusCode("Video failed", 400);
  var videoName = info.title.replace('|','').toString('ascii');
  const videoFileNameWithoutSlash = removeVideoSlash(videoName);
  var videoWritableStream = fs.createWriteStream('videos/' + videoFileNameWithoutSlash + '.mp3');
  var stream = videoReadableStream.pipe(videoWritableStream);
  callback(videoFileNameWithoutSlash) ;
}
```

**
Error is in flutter:: `java.io.eofexception`

It's important project**